# Angular 2 Material Design

Tags: angular, material-design

I am learning Angular 2 and I have so many problems with that whose one I can't find anything on that on internet. So, I tried easy thing to start : create a sign in form in my app, so I am using Material Design but my input are bad and nothing like in the Material Design Doc. Here so picture : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VC86.png)

So as you can see my input are not display and the placeholder is under it.

Here the code :

```html
<form >
    <md-input-container>
      <input mdInput type="email" placeholder="Email" >
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
      <input mdInput type="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" >
    </md-input-container>
   
    <button md-button type="submit" >Se connecter</button>
  </form>
```

What I missed ? Thank you so much.

Elisa

Comment: You did not install the Material Theme, please follow the getting started guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: The material Theme are mandatory ?

Comment: Yes it is required. Please follow the getting started guide. Everything is explained to get started with Angular Material.

Comment: I already read it. I follow it and include a prebuilt theme but that's the same, that's not works. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: How did you include it ?

Comment: I added this @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"; in my app.component.css

Comment: You are not supposed to add it to your app.component.css, but to your style.css. It is explained in the guide.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't see it. Thank you so much for your answer ! That 's working now. Have a good day.

Comment: I will post an answer so that people who have the same problem can find a solution, please don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added the theme to your `app.component.css` instead of the global `style.css` file.

More info about theming can be found here: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure getting started steps are followed and
2. `@NgModule({
     ...
     imports: [MdInputModule],
     ...
   })` 
   is added in angular module

Let me know if you need any help .

Comment: Thank you for you anwser. Someone help me, I forgot to include the theme.

Comment: No problem, I recently did project on Material Design, Ping me if you need help on any other topic.